# For a L.D.E $(x^{2}D^{2}−x(x+2)D+(x+2))y=0$, find the set, on which $xe^{x}$ and $x$ form the fundamental set of solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a linear differential equation, $(x^{2}D^{2} - x(x+2)D + (x+2))y= 0$, find the set, on which $xe^{x}$ and $x$ form the fundamental set of solutions.

The wronskian of $xe^{x}$ and $x$ is $0$ only at $x=0$ and non zero elsewhere.

Answer is given - $ x \in R / \{0\}$

Can I conclude, that whenever wronskian is $0$ at some points and non zero else where, then the solutions are not linearly independent only on those points$?$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow a fallacy, a mind-trap. The differential equation is singular at $x=0$, thus any domain of a solution of the equation as ODE can not contain the point $x=0$. It does not make sense to speak of linear dependence of solutions at points where these functions are not solutions.

Or the other way around, over every interval where the linear differential equation is regular, where its normalized form (leading coefficient $1$) has continuous coefficients, if the Wronskian is zero at one point, it is zero everywhere. So solutions are either linearly independent, and then that also means the pointwise version of linear independence in every point of the domain, or they are linearly dependent everywhere.

So in total, these functions are a system of linearly independent ODE solutions over $(-\infty,0)$ or over $(0,\infty)$, the domain of a solution is always a single open interval.

Comment: If I have a L.D.E, with leading coefficient $a_{0}(x)$, where $a_{0}(x) = 0$ at some point. Do I always need to eliminate that $x_{0}$ from the domain of solution in such questions$?$

Comment: By the way there was an $x$ instead of $e^{x}$, sorry for the typing mistake.

Comment: Yes, you have to exclude $x_0$ if you want a solution as ODE. Next you can categorize the singularity at $x_0$, if it is a regular singularity, that is, if the differential equation is a perturbation of an Euler-Cauchy DE, then one can still explore the local behavior of solutions around $x_0$ using the Frobenius method.