# Solution to IVP with singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working through a self-study on Differential Equations, primarily using the text "Differential Equations with Boundary Value Problems," 8th edition, Zill/Wright, but I'm also supplementing this with various materials I've found online. One such item is [this University of Illinois paper](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Etyson/existence.pdf) regarding existence and uniqueness theorems for first-order ODEs. In that paper it asks us to consider the first-order IVP
$$
y^{\prime}=\frac{2}{x}y,\quad y(x_0)=y_0.
$$
The functions $f(x,y)=2y/x$ and $\partial f/\partial y=2/x$ are defined and continuous in a neighborhood around each $(x,y),x\neq 0$, so we know there exists a unique solution defined in an open interval around $x_0\neq 0$. By separating variables and integrating, we derive solutions to this equation of the form
$$
y(x)=C x^2
$$
for any constant $C$.

The paper goes on to claim that all of these solutions **pass through** the point $(0,0)$, so the IVP
$$
y^{\prime}=\frac{2}{x}y,\quad y(0)=0
$$
has **infinitely many** solutions. But how can this be? As an abstract function of $x$, it is certainly true that $y(x)$ is defined and continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$, but as a solution of the given ODE, isn't the value $x=0$ necessarily excluded from its interval of definition? Isn't $x=0$ a singular point of the differential equation?

How can a solution of a differential equation exist through a point for which the derivative itself is not even defined?

EDIT:  It seems to me that the IVP
$$
x y^{\prime}=2y,\quad y(0)=0
$$
has $y=0$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$ as a valid, albeit trivial, solution (since there is nothing in the differential equation that explicitly disallows $x=0$), whereas the IVP
$$
y^{\prime}=\frac{2}{x}y,\quad y(0)=0
$$
has no solution since the value $x=0$ is not allowed.

Comment: Yes and no. That depends on how strictly you define "ODE". I also prefer that it is at least continuous on its domain, but other people prefer a more algebraic point-of-view, so if a solution formula exists on $\Bbb R$, they consider it an ODE solution on $\Bbb R$. Extended discussions in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3641660/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3517130/115115

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann for those references. I added a brief edit to my original post after reading those.